URLs with tracking parameters are indexed by Google in spite of Canonical tags
I have some URLs with parameters being indexed on Google. These parameters aren't of the filtering kind, they don't create millions of duplicates. The parameters are simply being used for tracking purposes, content doesn't change on the pages. We include rel="canonical" tags in these URLs, pointing to the original URLs without parameters. However, Google is ignoring these canonical tags and is indexing these URLs with parameters.
Most of these links don't have any kind of backlinks.
However, Google is showing these links for relevant branded keywords. And this is causing me issues such as:

It is showing links that features tracking codes of people who no longer work with us anymore.
It is spending crawl budget.

What should I do to solve these issues?
Some advise to use robots.txt and apply Disallow: /*?*
Some others apply noindex, follow
Some others suggest you to do both things.
But to be honest, I really don't know how to deal with these issues.
Any advice?

Have the canonical tags always been there? That should be the right answer.  If you've only just added them, then it may take a while to re-index.

Are both versions of the page being indexed, or just the one with the parameter?

Tracking parameters are a common cause of content duplication, but this should be easy to fix. In most cases, simply using Canonical <link> tags should do the trick. In your case, there seems to be something else causing trouble.
First, be advised that Google recommends against using any of the other methods that you have described, such as using noindex or blocking URLs with robots.txt. As a reminder, here are the best practices listed in Google's "How to specify a canonical URL with rel="canonical" and other methods" documentation page:

For all canonicalization methods, follow these best practices:

Don't use the robots.txt file for canonicalization purposes.
Don't use the URL removal tool for canonicalization. It hides all versions of a URL from Search.
Don't specify different URLs as canonical for the same page using different canonicalization techniques (for example, don't specify one URL in a sitemap, but a different URL for that same page using rel="canonical").
Don't specify a URL fragment as canonical, as Google generally doesn't support URL fragments.
We don't recommend using noindex to prevent selection of a canonical page within a single site, because it will completely block the page from Search. rel="canonical" link annotations are the preferred solution.
If you're using hreflang elements, make sure to specify a canonical page in the same language, or the best possible substitute language if a canonical page doesn't exist for the same language.
When linking within your site, link to the canonical URL rather than a duplicate URL. Linking consistently to the URL that you consider to be canonical helps Google understand your preference.


Note that this recommendations make complete sense: if a tracking parameter is set, it usually means that users are going to visit that URL. Therefore, setting these URLs as 404 or 410 errors or even redirecting them is never a good idea, as this will surely confuse users who clicked on one of these tracked URLs.
If Canonical tags are not enough to solve your issue, you probably have internal links pointing to one or more URLs containing a tracking parameter, e.g. the Homepage www.example.com/ linking to www.example.com/page-a?utm_source=whatever. You may also have other links pointing to other URLs with tracking parameters, but it's also possible that, on that first "seed" page, outgoing internal links are getting "polluted" with this tracking parameter, e.g. if www.example.com/page-a is linking to www.example.com/page-b, then it's possible that the same link on www.example.com/page-a?utm_source=whatever might be linking to www.example.com/page-b?utm_source=whatever instead of just www.example.com/page-b. This could result in all your site's pages getting duplicated by alternate URLs containing the ?utm_source=whatever tracking parameter. This is a critical internal linking issue that needs to be fixed by making sure that no unwanted query string parameters are added to any links in your pages.
Use your favorite website crawler to identify links containing tracking parameters. For example, with Screaming Frog, you can filter URLs with query string parameters by selecting the URL tab and the "Parameters" filter:

Then you can locate pages linking to these URls using the Inlinks tab in the details panel:

Finally, as stated in the aforementioned Google documentation page, make sure that your XML sitemap lists all the Canonical URLs that you would like indexed, and that it does not list any URL containing tracking parameters.
Hope this helps!

You cant fight Google. Each url including the params is unique.  Thats how it works.
In summary,

If you dont want a url, mark it as noindex, redirect it or return 404 or 410.
Remove internal links to these urls


Rohit thank you for your response.
When you say 'Remove internal links to these URLs,' can you elaborate on this point?
As I mentioned in the thread: 'These parameters aren't of the filtering kind—they don't create millions of duplicates. The parameters are simply used for tracking purposes, and the content on the pages remains unchanged.'
So, if I have a homepage with parameters, how do I remove internal links to these URLs?
